# Objective-C & Compare two NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, xcode4

I am trying to compare 2 NSStrings to see if they match but my app keeps crashing with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and it just shows me an assembly output and not the actually location within my code that it keeps crashing.

Here is my compare:

```
NSString *compareAlarm = [lblTime stringValue];
[lblTime setStringValue:[self getTime]];

if ([sAlarmTime isEqualToString:compareAlarm])
{
    NSLog(@"Alarm Hit");
}

[compareAlarm release];
```

Does anyone see why this would fail? If I comment out the if statement the crash stops.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what type is lblTime ? is compareAlarm nil in debug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you aren't retaining `compareAlarm` but you release it.

Comment: That was my problem. I was releasing an object and not retaining it. Thanks.

Comment: @dotNetNinja don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left) if it solved your problem.